# Styling multiple React apps with styled-components / styled-theming

Tags: reactjs, css, styled-components

I have a bunch of content-similar React apps to style, and I'm trying to shape a system, based on Styled-Components/Styled-Theming, to rule and modify their global styles just by changing the `<ThemeProvider />` theme prop.

I've been trying different options, and this is what seems to work best :

- an external `themes.js` file with all styles wrapped in a global object

```js
import theme from "styled-theming";

const backG = theme.variants("observatory", "backG", {
  positiveDark: {
    _OBS1: 'hsl(73, 65%, 50%)',
    _OBS2: 'hsl(210, 100%, 60%)',
  },
  negativeDark: {
    _OBS1: 'hsl(8, 70%, 63%)',
    _OBS2: 'hsl(0, 100%, 90%)',
  },
  actionDark: {
    _OBS1: 'hsl(53, 82%, 62%)',
    _OBS2: 'hsl(48, 100%, 50%)',
  },
});

const cursor = theme.variants("observatory", "cursor", {
  normal: {
    _OBS1: 'initial',
    _OBS2: 'initial',
  },
  pointer: {
    _OBS1: 'pointer',
    _OBS2: 'pointer',
  },
});

const fontS = theme.variants("observatory", "fontS", {
  h1: {
    _OBS1: "2.4rem",
    _OBS2: "2.25rem",
  },
  h2: {
    _OBS1: "2.2rem",
    _OBS2: "2rem",
  },
  h3: {
    _OBS1: "2rem",
    _OBS2: "1.75rem",
  },
});

const flexL = theme.variants("observatory", "flexL", {
  layout1: {
    _OBS1: "; display: flex; justify-content: center;",
    _OBS2: "; display: flex; justify-content: center;",
  },
  layout2: {
    _OBS1: "; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: flex-start;",
    _OBS2: "; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;",
  },
  layout3: {
    _OBS1: "; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;",
    _OBS2: "; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: flex-start;",
  }
});

const themes = {
  backG: backG,
  cursor: cursor,
  flexL: flexL,
  fontS: fontS,
}

export {themes};
```

- a CRA representing my app, with

  - an `index.js` file with 2 `<ThemeProvider />`, the first one referencing the external file, the second one dealing with themes inside of that external file

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

// styles
import {themes} from "./themes";
import {ThemeProvider} from "styled-components";

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={themes}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={{ observatory: "_OBS2" }}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

- an `App.js` file and other children components

```js
import React from 'react';

// styles
import styled, { injectGlobal } from "styled-components";

// components
import ThreeButtons from "./ThreeButtons";

injectGlobal`
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,500');

  html {
    font: 400 10px Roboto, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }

  body {
    font: 500 1.8rem Quicksand;
  }
`

const Wrapper1 = styled.div`
  display: ${props => props.theme.flexL};
  align-items: ${props => props.theme.flexL};
`

const App = () => (
  <Wrapper1 flexL="layout1">
    <ThreeButtons alignSelf1="center" flexL="layout2" />
    <ThreeButtons alignSelf2="flex-end" flexL="layout3" />
  </Wrapper1>
);

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";

// styles
import styled from "styled-components";

// components
import Button from "./Button";


const Wrapper1 = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  display: ${props => props.theme.flexL};
  flex-direction: ${props => props.theme.flexL};
  align-items: ${props => props.theme.flexL};
`

const ThreeButtons = (props) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Wrapper1
      flexL={props.flexL}
    >
      <Button
        backG="positiveDark"
        cursor="pointer"
        fontS="h1"
        label="lg-pos-button-pointer"
      />
      <Button
        alignSelf={props.alignSelf1}
        backG="negativeDark"
        cursor="pointer"
        fontS="h2"
        label="md-neg-button-pointer"
      />
      <Button
        alignSelf={props.alignSelf2}
        backG="actionDark"
        cursor="normal"
        fontS="h3"
        label="sm-act-button-nopointer"
      />
    </Wrapper1>
  </React.Fragment>
)

export default ThreeButtons;
```

```js
import React from "react";

// styles
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  align-self: ${props => props.alignSelf};
  background: ${props => props.theme.backG};
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.fontS};
  cursor: ${props => props.theme.cursor};
  padding: 1.2rem 1.8rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  filter: saturate(50%);
  transition: filter ease-in-out .15s;

  &:hover {
    filter: saturate(100%);
  }
`

const Button = (props) => (
  <StyledButton
    backG={props.backG}
    cursor={props.cursor}
    alignSelf={props.alignSelf}
    fontS={props.fontS}
  >
    {props.label}
  </StyledButton>
)

export default Button;
```

Like I said before, it looks like it works, but still there're 2 things I'm not really comfortable with because I don't get it :

- in the `themes.js` external file, I've been trying to create some kind of Flexbox mixins : to make it work, I must add an initial semicolon in the string value, or the first property is not considered and its value is not applied. Can someone explain me why ?
- in the `index.js` file, I must nest a `<ThemeProvider />` inside another one to make it work correctly : again, can someone explain me how Styled-Components and Styled-Theming are working together ?
- generally speaking, have you got any tips or advice to make my solution a better solution or to solve my initial problem, which was to globally style a bunch of content-similar React apps ?

If you need, you can find the entire code on GitHub : https://github.com/paillenapple/styles_sandbox

Thanks for your help.

Silvère